# Wireless guest access with HP ProCurve 420

Tags: security, wifi, hp, vlan, guest

We have a HP ProCurve 420 wireless access point hooked up to our LAN, which then connects to the internet though a gateway router.  Is it possible to set up a guest SSID, which can access the internet but not our LAN?

After reading through the manual, I don't see anything put forward as providing this function, but there are enough features to make me think I may have missed the implications of one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Procurve 420 supports multiple SSIDs, each of which can have different authentication settings and VLAN membership associated with it.

What you want to do is let your regular SSID be part of a VLAN that contains both your LAN and your router, and the guest SSID use a *different* VLAN that only contains your router.

Comment: The VLANs sounded promising, but I didn't see where to specify what they could connect to?

Comment: Since the Procurve 420 only has one 100Base-T port, there is no need to configure the VLANs other than associating them with an SSID (and optionally designating a single VLAN as untagged), the LAN port is implicitely a member of every used VLAN. You can then attach a VLAN-capable switch or router to the LAN port, which will allow you to treat each VLAN as a separate interface.

Comment: Needing to interface with other equipment is the detail I was missing.  Off to find my switch's manual.